Как организовать поиск по произвольным meta полям в wordpress
У меня есть два произвольных мета поля service и description которые выводятся на страницах авторов и мне необходимо чтобы пользователи могли искать авторов через поиск по этим мета полям. Что я имею в виду: через стандартный поиск wordpress пользователь осуществляет поиск который происходит по заданным произвольным мета полям и выводит всех авторов у которых есть заданные поисковые слова или фразы в этих мета полях. Прошу помощи так как уже все перепробовал.

Почему не использовать плагины? И надо понимать, что поиск по метаполям ресурсозатраная операция

Суть в том, что я уверен, что есть решение кодом а не грузить сайт плагинами тем более для задачи которая и так ресурсозатратная

Я пробовал этот вариант https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/creating-a-search-form-for-custom-fields но он выдает ошибку

Изучай https://wpmag.ru/2014/functions-php/

@SKarmanoff по незнанию и самостоятельно Вы ее можете сделать более ресурсозатратной, чем она есть, так как Вы ведь сами скорее всего не совсем понимаете в чем именно состоит ее ресурсозатратность

Спасибо большое за ваше внимание! Я прочитал статью и еще раз убедился что я совсем не имею знаний в области wordpress. Но проблему это так и не решило. я задал вопрос тем кто уже сталкивался с данной проблемой и возможно смог ее решить и может подсказать решение.

Тебе подсказали решение - плагины. Это значит готовые, из оф. каталога. А "код", который ты ожидаешь также нужно будет оформлять плагином (это не сложно), но будет скорее всего вызывать массу проблем и тормозов. Поэтому некоторые просто не хотят выступать в роли медведя, оказывающему плохую (а то и опасную) услугу.

Подскажите а вообще ищет ли поиск сами страницы авторов? просто у меня есть страницы типа /author/sergey/ и /author/mariya/ так вот там есть поизвольные поля но поиски во всех плагинах отказываются находить и выдавать эти страницы пользователей. как можно решить эту задачу?

Не посты этих пользователей а именно сами страницы авторов не ищет

Просто и в поиске страницы авторов не индексируются. как будто их не существует вообще

Да, стандартный поиск WordPress не включает архивы авторов

Тут немного не понятна реализация.
Допустим у нас есть страницы авторов. Скорее всего эти страницы реализованы как Посты (возможно свои кастомные посты). И в этих постах есть 2 кастомных поля.
В этом случае я бы получил WP_Query.
Примерно код выглядит так (у меня и в исходнике был запрос с таксонометрией, но произвольные поля вроде работают так же )
 $request[] =   new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'твой-тип-поста',
            'post_per_page' => -1,
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    //Тут твои произвольные поля
                )
            ),        
        ));

Дальше по классике.
 <?php while ($request -> have_posts()) :?>
        <?php $request->the_post(); ?> 
//Выводим результаты
<?php endwhile; ?>

Документация
https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#meta_query
Далее сам придумаешь. Из вопроса не до конца понятно, будет ли это RestAPI или будешь перенаправлять на страницу результата поиска.
